# multiple divs side by side of fixed width

Tags: css, html

I want 6 divs side by side to show service packages. The problem is I want all of them of specified pixel width. But I am unable to give them a width in pixel. And also the parent div is getting adjusted to the width acquired by them as I have specified the width of 80% to it. I checked other posts but they didn't help me. I am working on this code...

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="content" class="shadow">
            <div id="p-col1">
                <ul>
                    <li><h1>heading</h1></li>
                    <li>text text text </li>
                    <li class="grey">text text text </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="p-col2">
                <ul>
                    <li><h1>Heading</h1></li>
                    <li>text text </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="p-col3">
                <ul>
                    <li><h1>Heading</h1></li>
                    <li>text text </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="p-col4" class="shadow">
                <ul>
                    <li><h1>Heading</h1></li>
                    <li>text text </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="p-col5">
                <ul>
                    <li><h1>Heading</h1></li>
                    <li>text text </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="p-col6">
                <ul>
                    <li><h1>Heading</h1></li>
                    <li>text text </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- End of Main -->
```

The CSS:

```
   #main{
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:0px;
    font-size:18px;
}
.shadow {
    box-shadow:3px 0 10px #222 , -3px 0 10px #222;
    -moz-box-shadow:3px 0 10px #222 , -3px 0 10px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow:3px 0 10px #222 , -3px 0 10px #222;  
}
#main #content{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#p-col1{
    widht:100px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#p-col1 h1{
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#d1ebf1;
    padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}
#p-col2{
    widht:100px;
    background-color:#7098e0;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#p-col2 h1{
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#0152e7;
    padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}
#p-col3{
    widht:100px;
    background-color:#778cdd;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#p-col3 h1{
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#012edd;
    padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}
#p-col4{
    widht:100px;
    background-color:#75c3d7;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#p-col4 h1{
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#01abd8;
    padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}
#p-col5{
    widht:100px;
    background-color:#729fcc;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#p-col5 h1{
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#0b6dd0;
    padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}
#p-col6{
    widht:100px;
    background-color:#7098e0;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#p-col6 h1{
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#0189d4;
    padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}
li.grey{
    background-color:#e3e8e9;
}
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have spell mistakes in your css.... you have specified width as widht

Answer (score 4):

You can give them pixel `width`. But you have a typo. 
You have written `widht`, it should be `width`.

Comment: Ya Got it and Solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this `CSS`

```
#content { width: 100%; height: 150px; }
#p-col1, #p-col2, #p-col3, #p-col4, #p-col5, #p-col6 { width: 16%; height: 150px; float: left; }
```

or

```
.service-div { width: 16%; height: 150px; float: left; }

<div id="p-col1 service-div">
            <ul>
                <li><h1>heading</h1></li>
                <li>text text text </li>
                <li class="grey">text text text </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Do this for othre 5 `div`'s